# Responsive website for phone

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive website for mobile. I've just tried the following code to see if this works, but doesn't seem to make the code when I make my webpage smaller in chrome. Is this supposed to be like this or am I missing something? Or do I actually need to go on my phone and try the webpage out?

```
@media screen and(max-width:480px){
    body{
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space otherwise it is invalid code. https://jsfiddle.net/7fo28qrd/

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){//space between `and` and `(`
    body{
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks this worked! Can I ask a follow up question? What is the min-width:px for phones, generally speaking? Is there a general breakpoint that people have standarized? Because looking on my computerscreen when I make the page smaller doesn't really look like a phone size page

Comment: I would recommend reading up on break points: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints or use an out of the box solution like http://getbootstrap.com/